# $ \lim_{x \to 0^-}xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

*I cant use LHopital

I try to calculate: 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-}xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

i found this: [Evaluation of $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln (x)}{x}$ using Squeeze theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543930/evaluation-of-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-frac-ln-xx-using-squeeze-theor)

But it doesnt help, i cant use series.

Someone gave me an idea like this, but still im stuck:

define t = $e^{\frac{1}{x}} \Rightarrow \ln t = \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{\ln t}$

Therefore we get:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^-}xe^{\frac{1}{x}} = \displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t}{\ln t}$$

Now what?

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: Let $y=-1/x$ then ...

Comment: Let $L$ equal your limit then use $\ln(L)=\dots$; can you finish?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: You should check out the youtube channel: "Black pen red pen". This is just up your street and can be useful for similar work.

Comment: As $x \to 0^-$, $x \to 0$ and $e^{\tfrac{1}{x}} \to e^{-\infty} \to 0$. Since both limits exist, you have: $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} xe^{\tfrac{1}{x}} = \left(\lim_{x \to 0^-}x \right)\left(\lim_{x \to 0^-}e^{\tfrac{1}{x}}\right) = 0\cdot 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 4):

You can proceed directly:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(xe^{\frac 1x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}x\cdot \lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{\frac 1x}=0\cdot 0=0 $$
Note that $\frac 1x\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{1/x}=\lim_{y\to -\infty }e^{y}
$$